# Enable next form element with the value of previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do need to create a form. In that form I need to enable form element one by one. That mean, If an user entered valid data to first element then I want to autofocus next element and so on.

**NOTE:** When page is load I want to keep all the elements disable except first element.

This is HTML of my form.

```
<form role="form" class="banner" method="post" action=""> 

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control first-name sequence" autocomplete="off" required>
      <label for="name" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Enter Your Name"></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control email_address sequence" autocomplete="off" disabled required>
      <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" rel="tooltip" title="Enter Your Email"></label>
      <span class="email-error"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number Eg: xx-xxx-xxx" class="form-control phone-number sequence" autocomplete="off" disabled required>
      <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" rel="tooltip" title="Enter Your Phone Number"></label>
    </div>
  </div>                      

  <div class="element-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
        <input type="text" name="charter-date" placeholder="Pick Up Date" class="form-control datepicker sequence" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="date" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" rel="tooltip" title="Prefered Charter Date"></label>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="element-right">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
        <input type="text" name="charter-time" placeholder="Pick Up Time" class="form-control timepicker sequence" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="time" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" rel="tooltip" title="Time of Charter"></label>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div> 

  <p class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">
      <span class="btn-orange-inner">Send</span>
    </button>
  </p>
</form>
```

This is how I tried it in jQuery:

```
// form validation 
function fakeValidator(event) {
  var flag = false;    
  var $element = $(event.target);
  var values = $element.val();

  if (values.length >= 3) {  

    if($element.hasClass('email_address')) {
      if(validemail(values)){              
        flag = true ;
      }else{        
        flag =false;
      }
    }
    flag =true;     
  } else {        
    flag =false;
  }

  if(flag){ 
    //alert('hi');
    $element.addClass('valid');
    enableNextElement(event);     
  } else{
    alert('hi el');
    $element.removeClass('valid');
    //$element.addAttr('disabled');
  }
}

function validemail(value){
  var emailReg ="/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/";
}

function enableNextElement(event) {
  var $element = $(event.target);
  if ($element.hasClass('valid')) {
      $element.closest('.form-group')
          .next('.form-group')
          .find('.sequence')
          .removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}

$('.sequence').on('blur keyup', fakeValidator);
```

But my problem is, if I entered an invalid email next element is enabling. But I want to enable next element if its a valid email in email field.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this? 
Thank you.

Comment: This a demo with current coding - http://jsbin.com/cakizituce/edit?js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things:

> - You should `return true` or `false` from your email validation    function i.e. `validemail`
> - Your `regex` is stored as string, and hence you cannot apply `test` function on it. Remove wrapping it in `" "`

Above mentioned changes will give you desired result.

```
function validemail(value){
  var emailReg =/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/; //regex
    return emailReg.test(value); //use test which returns true or false
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/g06e7da7/2/)**

It will still enable the `phonenumber` because you have `validation` written in such a way.

*Your Validation:*

```
if (values.length >= 3) {  
   //this is ok for name
   if($element.hasClass('email_address')) {
        if(validemail(values)){              
            flag = true;
        }else{        
            flag =false;//even though flag is false here
        }
   }
   flag =true; //when it comes to this line it again makes it to true
   //and for email along with length>3, valid email address has also to be validated
} else {        
    flag =false;
}
```

*My workaround*

```
if (values.length >= 3) {  
    flag =true; //set this first
    if($element.hasClass('email_address')) {//then perform other validations
        if(validemail(values)){              
           flag = true ;
        }else{        
           flag =false;
        }
    }
} else {        
    flag =false;
}
```

Comment: It is enabling `phone_number` field weather email is valid or not valid

Comment: Yes dear. Now its working nicely. One more question, Can we write these function in a reusable way?

Comment: I asked about `fakeValidator`, `validemail` and `enableNextElement`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92798/discussion-between-user3733831-and-guruprasad-rao).